# PDF Button on an Access Custom Ribbon ( USysRibbons )

Tags: ms-access

I have created an Access Custom Ribbon, with buttons to ‘Print’, ‘Save As PDF’ and ‘Close Print Preview’.

```
    <group id="ReportingToolbar" label="Reports Toolbar">
         <button     idMso="FilePrintQuick"                label="Print All"             enabled="true"     size="large"     supertip="Print All"/>
         <button     idMso="FileSaveAsPdfOrXps"     label="Print PDF"           enabled="true"     size="large"     supertip="PDF This Document"/> 
         <button     idMso="PrintPreviewClose"        label="Close Report"     enabled="true"     size="large"     supertip=" Close Report"/>
    </group>
```

While the ‘Save As PDF’ works, it’s a bit clunky, having to choose a location to save the PDF each time.

I have written a Function to try to do this.  It works perfectly when run from a Form, as I can supply the Report Name, the File Location and any Criteria/Where Clause, but I cannot get it to work through a custom ribbon.

```
Public Function OpenReportAsPDF(reportName, fileName, Optional criteria)
    
        Dim File_Location As String
    
        File_Location = PMG_Location & "\Temp_Files\" & fileName & ".pdf"
    
        DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewPreview, , criteria, acHidden
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, acFormatPDF, File_Location
        DoCmd.close acReport, reportName, acSaveNo
    
        Application.FollowHyperlink fileName
    End Function
```

When I try to call this Function from the Ribbon using an ‘onAction’ argument, I don’t know how to supply the ‘reportName’ that is currently being Previewed, or a ‘filename’ or any ‘criteria’ so the Function errors with ‘Argument not optional’

The built in idMso="FileSaveAsPdfOrXps" ribbon HTML somehow knows what Report is currently being Previewed, but I don’t know how to programmatically supply the File Location and to open the PDF after it has been saved.

What I am looking for is a PDF button on my custom ribbon, to save the currently Previewed report and open it in the default PDF application.

I hope you can help.

Many thanks

Mark

Comment: "Cannot get it to work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Your ribbon HTML does not show onAction argument calling function. https://www.accessribbon.de/en/index.php?Access_-_Ribbons:Callbacks:Button